# Trouble fetching token from localstorage - React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I'm new with react and i'm trying to create a basic login function using local storage and tokens.

I can see in my devtools that a token is actually stored but when i refresh the page, my application seems to have some trouble fetching it.

These are the two js-files in which i think the problem is located:

```
function Mypage () {
   
    const { token, setToken } = useToken();

     if(!token) {
        return <Login setToken={setToken} />
    }
 
  return (
      <>
    <h1>My page</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default Mypage
```

```
export default function useToken() {
  
     const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken?.token
  };    

   /*    const getToken = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        return token !== null;
      };   */

  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

I tried to mess around with two different const in which the commented out did work in "Mypage", but i would like it to be gathered in the same function "useToken".

Can anyone please give some input in where i might be messing up?

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from your code is that there is a function to `getToken` which returns the token but you are not getting the token. In return, call
the `getToken` function like you set `saveToken`.

```
return { 
   setToken: saveToken, 
   token: getToken 
}
```

Comment: Tried it. The condition !token is always true, no matter if there is a token in local storage or not.

Comment: The approach is not looking right. The saveToken receive userToken parameter. But I can't see userToken is passed to saveToken

Comment: The flow should be like this: User login in app. The server sends the token and you set token using `localstorage.setItem`.  Then in Mypage just use `localstorage.getItem` to get token. If there is not token then redirect to Login page. Token should be set in Login page, and then get token in Mypage or any other component.

Comment: I do have another login js-file in which i have an async onpost method.

Comment: Right. If token is setting correctly then first try to get token `localstorage.getItem` in Mypage instead of using useToken()

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to pass the setToken parameter when declaring routes in index.js? Right now login works fine if you access it through Mypage but when trying to login through login page it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: can you create an example code using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or codesandbox?